# I need to add 2 classes to a div, one is a string and another is from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add 2 classes to a div, one is a fixed string and another is from a variable. Here is a code example:

```
var foo = myObject.foo;
var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass("myClass" foo);
```

Would this work? I can't check it yet because I am rewriting my whole JavaScript file and I am not done yet.

If not would this work?:

```
var myClass = "myClass";
var foo = myObject.foo;
var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass(myClass foo);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: use + as a string concatenation operator in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string and the variable using `+`:

```
var foo = myObject.foo;
var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass("myClass " + foo);
```

Or

```
var myClass = "myClass";
var foo = myObject.foo;
var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass(myClass + " " + foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = myObject.foo;
var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass("myClass").addClass(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`$('<div></div>').addClass("myClass " + foo)`

Answer (score 0):

concatenate them with space:

```
 var bar = $('<div></div>').addClass(myClass+" "+foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myClass = "myClass";
var myObject = {
  foo:'class-one'
}
var foo = myObject.foo;
$('#test').addClass(myClass + ' ' + foo);
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red;
}
.class-one {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```